# Connecting to PostgreSQL-server with Hibernate from IntelliJ

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I am attempting to persist data to a PostgreSQL-database via Hibernate, have put in my user/pass, checked that it's working, made a db and some tables.
When I compile, I get an error

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server
requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.
```

I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate 2017.1 and have tried using both the supplied pg driver and 42.00 as external library.

I've had it working in previous versions, but never seen this one before. Must admit I'm not very good at this.
Basically, my defined password does not get correctly passed on to the server. It seems like it recognized my username. I've temporarily evaded this problem by modifying my pg_hba.conf file to trust local connections without password, but I am going to persist the data on an online server, so I'm gonna need a better fix.
The driver has a standard URL template that looks like this:

```
jdbc:postgresql:{database::postgres}[\?<&,user={user:param},password={password:param},{:identifier}={:param}>]
```

Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/gigahertz</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <mapping class="no.hvl.dat101.gigahertz.ReservationJPA"/>

    <!-- <property name="connection.username"/> -->
    <!-- <property name="connection.password"/> -->

    <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
    <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
</session-factory>
```

Here is my generated Main-class

```
package no.hvl.dat101.gigahertz;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Metamodel;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import javax.persistence.metamodel.EntityType;

import java.util.Map;

/**
 */
public class Main {
    private static final SessionFactory ourSessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();

            ourSessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
        return ourSessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Session session = getSession();
        try {
            System.out.println("querying all the managed entities...");
            final Metamodel metamodel = session.getSessionFactory().getMetamodel();
            for (EntityType<?> entityType : metamodel.getEntities()) {
                final String entityName = entityType.getName();
                final Query query = session.createQuery("from " + entityName);
                System.out.println("executing: " + query.getQueryString());
                for (Object o : query.list()) {
                    System.out.println("  " + o);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Your config doesn't set a username or password, not in the URL, nor using the `connection.*` properties. Also note that this is not a compile-time error, but an exception at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Mark. I have added login info in the GUI. I tried adding user/pass to the URL in the xml file with the pattern url?username=username&password=password, that didn't work. I then tried using the commented-out properties, but it gave me a compiler error saying those kind of properties were not allowed inside the <session factory>.
Can I use a connection.-property from the Main file in order to define the password? If you could point me to the correct syntax at the correct place I would be very grateful. I thought IntelliJ would pass this 'under the hood' in a secure manner.

Comment: A sample Connection string that could be used is this: `"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb?currentSchema=testdb&user=postgres&password=postgres")`

Comment: As this is XML, `&` needs to be replaced with `&amp;` instead.

Comment: Eagle eyes, @MarkRotteveel

Comment: The solution to this was to add the parameters in the try block in main in the form configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username","username) etc

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was to add the parameters in the try block in main in the form configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username","u‌​sername) etc.
For some reason, the login details were not passed correctly by IntelliJ to the server.